Product variety in aldol condensation in acidic medium
Why do acid catalysed aldol condensation give more variety of products compared to base catalysed aldol condensation?
For example, acid catalysed aldol condensation of acetone also produces some 2,6-dimethylhepta-2,5-dien-4-one.
But why can't base catalysed aldol condensation of acetone also give the above mentioned product?
After the formation of the first condensate, shouldn't it be possible for another enolate to form using the alpha hydrogen from the other side of the carbonyl group, leading to the above mentioned product?
